# Get row id in SQuirreL

Tags: sql, squirrel-sql

I want to get back the row id on the left hand side along with the rest of the columns is that possible?

```
SELECT * from
WSJ0CPP  
WHERE  J0YOCD = '08' AND J0ACCD = '01';
```

I am using SQuirreL.